# How to fix leap year Date

Tags: sql, date-format, leap-year

I'm having issues with Leap Year what can i do to change it to 28 feb or 1st march

i'm getting the below error,

**Msg 289, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.**

```
SELECT
cast(MEMNO as int) MEMNO,
cast(YEAR(EXITDATE) as int)  
[StartYear],
case WHEN DATEFROMPARTS(cast(YEAR(GETDATE()) as int)+1, 
DATEPART(m, EXITDATE), DATEPART(d, EXITDATE))<=GETDATE() THEN cast(YEAR(GETDATE()) as int)   else cast(YEAR(GETDATE()) as int)  END  [EndYear]
FROM EXITRETIREMENT
group bY
cast(MEMNO as int),
cast(YEAR(EXITDATE) as int),
EXITDATE





 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EXITRETIREMENT](
[MEMNO] [int] NULL,
[EXITDATE] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EXITRETIREMENT] ([MEMNO], [EXITDATE]) VALUES (45517,CAST(N'2004-02-29T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
```

Comment: I've tried your query asumming memmo is smallint and exitdate is a date and its syntax is correct, what actual data type are those fields?

Comment: you should post the data and dbms

Comment: Your `case` is to produce always the same `cast(YEAR(GETDATE())`. Are you sure? What is the logic you want ?

Comment: Don't increment the YEAR of 2020-02-29, use DATEADD(year, 1, '2020/02/29')

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57530882/what-are-some-examples-of-leap-year-bugs

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be running in MSSQL, because DATEFROMPARTS exists in MSSQL.

The query:

```
Select
    Cast(MEMNO As int) MEMNO,
    Cast(Year(EXITDATE) As int) StartYear,
    Case
        When DateFromParts(Cast(Year(GetDate()) As int) + 1, DatePart(m, EXITDATE), DatePart(d, EXITDATE)) <= GetDate()
        Then Cast(Year(GetDate()) As int)
        Else Cast(Year(GetDate()) As int)
    End EndYear
From
    EXITRETIREMENT
Group By
    Cast(MEMNO As int),
    Cast(Year(EXITDATE) As int),
    EXITDATE
```

is building a date: `DateFromParts(Cast(Year(GetDate()) As int) + 1, DatePart(m, EXITDATE), DatePart(d, EXITDATE))`

With the following parameters:

- year from the current year +1
- month from EXITDATE
- day from EXITDATE

When EXITDATE is 29th February, and next year is not a leap year, than you will indeed have a problem.

Consider rewriting the DATEFROMPARTS to: `DATEADD(year,1,EXITDATE)`

or, when it needs to be next year:

```
DATEADD(year,year(GETDATE()-year(EXITDATE)+1,EXITDATE)
```